# Passing an Argument Value to the Data Object as a Key in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I'm creating a page that contains 4 different tables for now. All rows in each table will have update and delete buttons. I can make everything work when I code all CRUD functions for each table separately. But what I want to do is create a function for update action for example, and pass the table name as an argument.

```
<tr v-for="asset in assets" :key="asset.id">
  <td>{{asset.id}}</td>
  <td>{{asset.name}}</td>
  <td>{{asset.category.name}}</td>
  <td>
    <a href @click.prevent="editDialog(asset, 'asset')">Edit</a>
    <a href @click.prevent="deleteThis(asset.id)">Delete</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This is the pop-up window for edit and create an item:

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog">
 <div v-if="editMode">
   <div v-if="target_table == 'asset'">
     <form>...</form>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div v-else>...</div>
</v-dialog>
```

I have those things in script

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false,
      editMode: false,
      target_table: "",
      assets: {},
      asset: new Form({
        id: "",
        name: "",
        category: "",
      }),
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchAssets() {
      axios.get("/api/assets").then(({ data }) => (this.assets = data));
    },
    editDialog(data, table) {
      this.target_table = table;
      this.editMode = true;
      this.dialog = true;
      this.table.fill(data);
    },
  },
}
```

And here is my problem. If you look at the last row of the code, I'm trying to fill a form named "asset" that comes with editDialog(asset, 'asset') as its second parameter. But with this syntax, Vuejs goes to data object and look for a "table" as a key instead of "asset" and I'm getting "table is not defined" error. How can I make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to change `this.table.fill(data);` with `this.$data[table].fill(data)`

Let me know if it works